# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'

Tags: machine-learning, python, predictive-modeling, pandas, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean the data. But I don't know how to remove a function from a column in data frame.[image]

At row number 473 it show column N has a function . How it should be filtered out ?

Comment: Could you add your code and specify which library you are using?

Comment: @Archie Its solved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a generic way to convert pandas column to numeric dtype:

```
df['col_name'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col_name'], errors='coerce')
```

this will replace all values, that couldn't be converted to numeric values with NaN's (Not a Number).

PS you may want to analyze how and why do you have a reference to a lambda function in your cells. Fixing the source of that problem would be a more appropriate solution.